# Why use a hex literal for an int?

Tags: c#, int, hex

Whilst reading over some existing code I came across:

```
public static readonly int MaxSize = 0x1000;
```

Which made me wonder why use a hex literal. In this context MaxSize is used for pagination.

The closest I came to was:

> Hex numbers are a convenient way of expressing integral values,
>   denoting exactly the bits stored in memory for that integer.

https://csharp.2000things.com/2010/08/28/72-hexadecimal-numbers/

Which makes sense to a degree, I'd be interested in hearing a more detailed explanation for this use case in particular "denoting exactly the bits stored in memory".

Comment: For example to describe bit masks. But for this use case I don't see any meaningful explanation of doing it with hex literals despite trying to confuse other programmers or trying to be a 'cool' programmer.

Comment: It's hard to tell the reasoning behind this without asking the programmer that wrote it or seeing the context in which it's used. The maximum size of what exactly?

Comment: In some cases, (error) states in specifications are expressed in hex literals, so to match the specification the developer can express the respective values in code also in hex literals.

Comment: Thanks @ckruczek I have seen it used for bit masks in this code base, but I've added more detail to it's context. I agree that some programmers might use such a technique to appear cool and worthwhile mentioning, but knowing my predecessors and the rigorous code reviews undertaken I don't suspect that is the case in this example.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I've added some additional detail to the context.

Comment: It's a matter of choice of the programmer. For example I use them if and only if  it's a bit masks or it represents a power of 2 or a power of 2 minus 1. A case cound be whwn one wants to make a bitwise AND to extract a certain number of bits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In some cases HEX value is more rounded and understandable than its decimal equivalent. Like 0x0FFF, 0xA0A0, 0x10000, etc.

Comment: Interesting thanks, do you have examples where the more rounded understandable HEX might be appropriate?

Comment: @AlexKeySmith For example, 64K limit can be checked with `0x10000` or `0xFFFF`. For 32+ bit integers the risk of mistake with `4294967295` is much higher than `0xFFFFFFFF`.